# Undesired validation error message produced from a form bound to string property: The value '' is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation, model-view-controller

If a user submits an empty value, I would like the following validation error to be displayed: "The Comment field is required."

However, the actual validation error produced is: "The value '' is invalid".

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class CommentsViewModel
{
    public int TranslationSetId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string NewComment { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TranslationSetComment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my POST action method:

```
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AddCommentFromTranslationSetDetailView(
        CommentsViewModel commentsViewModel,
        [FromServices] ITranslationSetDetailBuilderService builderService)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            TranslationSetDetailViewModel model = await builderService.BuildTranslationSetDetailViewModelAsync(commentsViewModel.TranslationSetId);
            model.CommentsViewModel = commentsViewModel;
            return View("TranslationSetDetail", model);
        }
        else
        {
            await _translationSetService.AddCommentAsync(_userLocator.CurrentUserId, commentsViewModel.TranslationSetId, commentsViewModel.NewComment);
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(TranslationSetDetail), new { TranslationSetId = commentsViewModel.TranslationSetId.ToString() });
        }
    }
```

Here is the HTML Partial:

```
<a data-toggle="collapse"
   href="@string.Concat("#add-comment-collapse", Model.TranslationSetId.ToString())"
   aria-expanded="false"
   aria-controls="@string.Concat("add-comment-collapse", Model.TranslationSetId.ToString())">
    <p>Add a comment</p>
</a>
<div class="collapse" id="@string.Concat("add-comment-collapse", Model.TranslationSetId.ToString())">

    <form class="add-comment-form"
          asp-controller="@nameof(Home)"
          asp-action="@nameof(Home.AddCommentFromTranslationSetDetailView)"
          method="post">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="TranslationSetId" value="@Model.TranslationSetId" />
        <span asp-validation-for="NewComment" class="text-danger"></span>
        <textarea asp-for="NewComment" class="form-control"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-2">Add</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-light my-2">Cancel</button>
        <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
    </form>

</div>
```

**Please note:** I have put my form inside of partial. I don't see a reason why this should have an effect, but just in case, below is the line of code where I use the partial:

```
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <hr />
                                <h4>Comments:</h4>
                                <partial name="_TranslationSetDetailCommentsPartial" for="CommentsViewModel" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Here is a screenshot from my running application. In the image you can see the validation error message that is produced after I tried to submit an empty form:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the ModelState from a form submitted without entering a value into the text field.

[image]

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to look at this issue and please let me know if you would like any further code snippets etc.

Comment: Try using this annotation in your ViewModel  [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Comment field is required.")]

Comment: Hi @GraemeC, I've made the changes you suggested but it did not solve the issue. It appears that the ModelState is being invalidated by some other thing. However, I'm really struggling to understand what that other thing could be.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this attribute in this way;

```
[
    Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, 
    ErrorMessage = "some error message here")
]
```